# NodeJS does not work after uprading from version 8.11.1

Tags: node.js, angular

I decided to upgrade my version of nodejs from 8.11.1 to 10.15.3. I am running on Windows 10 so I downloaded v10.15.3-x64.msi file. I created a brand new Angular application from "ng new" command and I got the "HTTP ERROR 400" page with no error in the console.

[image: screenshot]

I have cleared the cache, reboot the system and nothing helps. When I will go back to node JS version 8.11.1 everything starts to work again. The newest version of nodejs v11.11.0-x86.msi also doesn't work for me.

How this can happen and how can I get any information what is going on?

**EDIT**: this is not a duplication of any existing topics about upgrading NodeJS, because the new version is seen by the system and all components - see the console result in the screenshot I provided. After upgrading the NodeJs all my solutions based on that technology stoped working showing HTTP Error 400 page. After degrading to v8 everything starts working again.

Comment: Press `F12` to open developer tools, and then hold the `CTRL` key while clicking down on the refresh icon in Chrome. Wait until a drop down menu appears and then select "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: Same result. No error in Chrome debugger.

Comment: Try using a different browser like Firefox or Edge or use curl on the command line.

Comment: @cgTag changing browser doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came back when I had to install newer version of node (12.14.1), so this time it worked. Additionally I deleted folders that prompted from runnig  `where npm` command after deleting an old version.